# Magento 2 varnish not caching, delivers new cookie each time

Tags: magento, caching, cookies, varnish

I'm trying to get Varnish to cache a magento store but it keeps setting different cookies each time I curl it:

```
$ curl -IL -X GET https://myurl.com/ |grep cookie
set-cookie: store=default; expires=Sat, 17-Apr-2021 19:51:22 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/index.php/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=j5uhb0oe5qh8d212j12sfcnsaa; expires=Fri, 17-Apr-2020 20:51:22 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=myurl.com; HttpOnly

$ curl -IL -X GET https://myurl.com/ |grep cookie
set-cookie: store=default; expires=Sat, 17-Apr-2021 19:51:26 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/index.php/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=dg09e4uaj9kiqo37rp4pk2g8co; expires=Fri, 17-Apr-2020 20:51:26 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=myurl.com; HttpOnly
```

Website is loading pretty slow.
My varnish config:

```
import std;

# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}


acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "172.25.0.0"/16;
}

sub vcl_recv {

 # set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend(); # send all traffic to the vdir director

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }

        # If all Tags should be purged clear
        # # ban everything to catch assets as well
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern == ".*") {
         ban("req.url ~ .*");
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged Magento"));
    }


    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "/healthcheck") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        #return (pass);
    return (hash);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    #if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404)) {
    # don't cache 404 nor 300 nor 500
    if (beresp.status != 200) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    set resp.http.X-Test = "YEAH";

    if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
      set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
      set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
    # Please note that obj.hits behaviour changed in 4.0, now it counts per objecthead, not per object
    # and obj.hits may not be reset in some cases where bans are in use. See bug 1492 for details.
    # So take hits with a grain of salt
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Caché:

$ bin/magento cache:status

Current status:

```
                    config: 1
                    layout: 0
                block_html: 0
               collections: 1
                reflection: 1
                    db_ddl: 1
                       eav: 1
     customer_notification: 1
        config_integration: 1
    config_integration_api: 1
                 full_page: 0
                 translate: 1
         config_webservice: 1
                    vertex: 0
         wp_gtm_categories: 1
```

## php bin/magento config:show |grep -i cache

```
system/full_page_cache/varnish/access_list - localhost
system/full_page_cache/varnish/backend_host - localhost
system/full_page_cache/varnish/backend_port - 8080
system/full_page_cache/varnish/grace_period - 300
system/full_page_cache/caching_application - 2
```

Is this expected? site loads extremely slow, even if I reload it over and over again

Thanks for your time, gentleman.

Comment: You have `full_page: 0` and then why you have an expectation of cache? :)

Comment: It was enabled, I disabled it troubleshooting PHPSESSID generation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on de `VCL` code, it doesn't look like Varnish is removing the `PHPSESSID` and the `store` cookies. One way to be sure, is by running the following `varnishlog` command on your Varnish server:

```
varnishlog -g request -i ReqUrl -I ReqUnset:cookie -I ReqHeader:Cookie -I bereqheader:Cookie -I berequnset:cookie  -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

This will look at requests from requests to the homepage and will list the following things:

- URL
- Cookies set by the client as a request header
- A copy of the cookies, set as a backend request header
- Possible cookies being unset in the client part of the VCL *(e.g. in `vcl_recv`)*
- Possible cookies being unset in the backend part of the VCL *(e.g. in `vcl_backend_request`)*

This will give you a clear indication whether or not cookies are remove by Varnish. You can replace the `cookie` header filter with any other header potentially being removed.

If you want to know which VCL flow is run, you can add `-i "VCL_*"` and then you'll see if it is a *HIT*, a *MISS*, or a deliberate *PASS*.

Once you've done the necessary debugging, you'll know if it is a Varnish issue, or a PHP issue.

Comment: right, the cookies are not removed. But in sub vcl_recv is ending with: return (hash) . So the cookies are ignored and varnish is instructed to go to the hash routine.

Answer (score 0):

check for X-Magento-Vary cookie. It might be on a Ajax response and this cookie is in hash routine